# How to sort a List<String> of formatted dates in dart?

Tags: flutter, sorting, date, dart

I have tried this on dartpad,

```
void main() {
  final List<String> dates=["24-06-2021","27-05-2021","21-04-2021","29-07-2021","15-12-2021"];
  var sorted = dates..sort((a,b) => a.compareTo(b));
  print(sorted);
}
```

Output : [15-12-2021, 21-04-2021, 24-06-2021, 27-05-2021, 29-07-2021]
Desired : [21-04-2021, 27-05-2021, 24-06-2021, 29-07-2021, 15-12-2021]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: an hour ago i gave you a solution with integers, the same works with `DateTime` objects

Comment: This code works, `
void main() {
  final List<String> dates=["2021-06-24","2021-05-24"];
  var sorted = dates.map(DateTime.parse).toList()..sort((a,b) => a.compareTo(b));
  for(int i =0;i<sorted.length;i++){
    String date = '${sorted[i].day}-${sorted[i].month}-${sorted[i].year}';
    print(date);
  }
} ` but is it efficient. @pskink

Comment: That's as efficient as you can get.  You can't do a comparison-based sort faster than O(n log n), and converting everything to `DateTime` objects first means that you don't need to reparse the same strings when performing multiple comparisons of the same element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

List<String> getSortedDates(List<String> dates){

  //Formatting for acceptable DateTime format
  DateFormat formatter = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

  //Mapping to convert into appropriate dateFormat
  List<DateTime> _formattedDates = dates.map(formatter.parse).toList();
  
  //Apply sort function on formatted dates
  _formattedDates.sort();

  //Mapping through sorted dates to return a List<String> with same formatting as passed List's elements
  return _formattedDates.map(formatter.format).toList();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';


 List dates = ["24-06-2021",
                  "27-05-2021",
                  "21-04-2021",
                  "29-07-2021",
                  "15-12-2021"];

  List<DateTime> newdates = [];
  DateFormat format = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

  for (int i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    newdates.add(format.parse(dates[i]));
  }
  newdates.sort((a,b) => a.compareTo(b));

  for (int i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    print(newdates[i]);
  }
```

Comment: Date format needs to be fixed to dd-MM-yyyy

Comment: Thanks guys, have tweaked it a little bit and finally got my code.